# Diagonalizability of a certain linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $F$ be a field and $n$ a positive integer. If $A\in M_n(F)$ then we can define a linear operator $T:M_n(F)\rightarrow M_n(F)$, given by $T_A(B):=AB-BA$. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then it is not dufficult to show that $T_A$ is also diagonalizable. But is the converse true? If necessary, we may assume that $F$ is algebraically closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the algebraically closed case.

First, let us assume that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^t$.

Define $W=\text{span}\{vw^t, v\in\ker(A^n) \text{ and } w\in\ker((A^t)^n)\}$

Since $A(\ker(A^n))\subset \ker(A^n)$ and $A^t(\ker((A^t)^n))\subset \ker((A^t)^n)$, we have  $T_A(W)\subset W.$

Notice also that $(T_A|_{W})^{2n+1}\equiv 0$.

If we assume that $T_A$ is diagonalizable then $T_A|_{W}$ is too.

Since$(T_A|_{W})^{2n+1}\equiv 0$, it implies that $T_A|_{W}\equiv 0$.

Hence, if $vw^t\in W$ then $Avw^t=vw^tA$. So $Av=\lambda v$ and $A^tw=\mu w$.

Therefore $0=A^nv=\lambda^nv$ and $0=(A^t)^nw=\mu^nw$ by the definition of $W$.

So $\lambda=\mu=0$, which implies $v\in Ker(A)$, $w\in Ker(A^t)$.   Thus, the index of the eigenvalue $0$ is 1.

But we can repeat the same argument with any eigenvalue $\lambda$, just by noticing that $T_A=T_{A-\lambda Id}$.

Comment: I do not understand why $(T_A|_W)^{2n+1}=0$. Could you please explain? Also, i do not understand why $Avw^t=vw^tA$ implies that $Av=\lambda v$ and $A^tw=\mu w$.

Comment: @sagnikchakraborty Hi. Notice that $T_A^k(B)=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}A^jBA^i$ where $i+j=k$ (Write down some examples to convince yourself or use induction). Hence i or j is greater or equal to k/2.   If $k\geq 2n$ and $B\in W$, $A^jBA^i=0$ then $T_A|_{W}^k\equiv 0$. I used $k=2n+1$, but i could have used $k=2n$. Let me answer below your second question.

Comment: @sagnikchakraborty If we choose $w\neq 0$ then some of its coordinates $w_i\neq 0$. Let $e_i^t=(0,...,1,0,..,0)$ (1 occupies position i). Since $Avw^t=vw^tA$, we get $w_iAv=Avw^te_i=vw^tAe_i$. Hence $Av=\lambda v$.

Comment: So did you prove that $\text{ker }(A)=\text{ker }(A^n)$? But that is not correct. Am i making some mistake?

Comment: @sagnikchakraborty Yes. I proved that $ker(A)=ker(A^n)$. Notice that $ker(A)=Ker(A^n)$ only occurs when the index of the eigenvalue 0 is 1.

Comment: From $Avw^t=vw^tA$, how do you conclude that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $w$ is an eigenvector of $A^t$?

Comment: OK, i think i understand it now. If $A$ does not have the same algebraic and geometric multiplicity at $0$, then let $v\in \text{ker }A^2\setminus\text{ker }A$ and $w\in \text{ker }(A^t)^2\setminus\text{ker }A^t$. Then $vw^t\in W$, implying that $Avw^t=vw^tA$. Multiplying both sides by $A$ on the left, we get $(Av)(A^tw)^t=0$, implying that either $Av=0$ or $A^tw=0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, my question is settled over algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @sagnikchakraborty You are welcome